# What forbids the cubic term in the expansion of free energy functional with external field $H\neq 0$?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, symmetry, phase-transition, symmetry-breaking

The free energy functional $F[m]$ in presence of a nonzero external magnetic field $H$ can be expanded in terms of the magnetization (an example of an order parameter) as $$F[m]=F_0+a(T) m^2+b(T) m^4-Hm\tag{1}.$$ Why doesn't one consider $m^3$ term in this case? In presence of a magnetic field, there is a preferred sign form the value of $m$, either positive or negative.

I agree, and as pointed out by @knzhou that higher order odd terms can be neglected. But I don't understand yet why should $m^3$ be neglected.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62536/discussion-on-question-by-srs-what-forbids-the-cubic-term-in-the-expansion-of-fr).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to think of $F[m]$ as composed of two parts: a system-specific part, that is *independent* of the external field $H$, and an interaction part, which depends on $H$. I will call the first contribution $F_s$ (for "system") and the second $F_i$ (for "interaction"):

$$F[m,H] = F_s[m] + F_i[m,H]$$

Usually, we assume that the external field is weak, so that $F_i$ is linear in $H$.

The lowest terms of $F_s$ are

$$\tag{1}\label{1}F_s[m] = a_1 |\nabla m|^2 + a_2 m^2 + a_3 m^3 + a_4 m^4 + ...$$

where the $a_k$ depend on temperature and on the wavenumber. Notice that there is no linear term (see my answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/259124/question-about-ginzburg-landau-theory/) for an explanation).

If the Hamiltonian of the system is invariant for the transformation $m \to -m$, then no odd-power term can appear in \ref{1}. This is because the system-specific part must have the same symmetry of the Hamiltonian. Notice that the presence of the external field changes nothing, because it is $F_s$ that has to possess this symmetry, and it is *independent* on $H$.